# Calculating the relationship between two numbers

Tags: percentages

I have a ridiculous problem I need help with:

If **A:0,6m2** consumes **B:0,95ml** of something (say paper consumes water i.e.) how can I use these numbers to calculate any m2 to get the ml consumption? I want to know how much **1m2** consumes, based on that relation.

I know this is simple, but I can't for the life of me remember how.
I would greatly appreaciate any help.

Comment: You want the quantity "consumption per square meter" assuming it's linear? Well, 0.6m^2 consumes 0.95ml so 0.1m^2 consumes 0.95/6 ml and 1m^2 consumes 9.5/6 ml.

Comment: the _rule of three_ is what you are looking (sort of)

Comment: Thank you both so much. I'm reading up on that right now xyLe ( was hoping for a reference to "rules"). Thanks saldukoo for the immediate answer.